# Transparent background from images showing in my Slide show?

Tags: jquery

Because the all the images have a different angle and are all transparent you can see them all behind each other. Is there a way to only have the top image visible and the rest are hidden? can i hide the images in my .js file or .css?

I still want the image to be transparent and for now I have just added a background to go behind all images.

So I guess how can I keep the images in the slideshow transparent, but not show the images behind it.

http://kennenmen.netai.net/test.php

```
function slideSwitch() {
var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

$active.addClass('last-active');

$next.css({opacity: 1.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}

$(function() {
setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 400 );
});


    <div id="slideshow">
<img src="http://images.lasuni.com/users/5/0/kennen.png" alt="" class="active" />
<img src="http://images.lasuni.com/users/2/0/kennen.png" alt="" />
<img src="http://images.lasuni.com/users/8/0/kennen.png" alt="" />
<img src="http://images.lasuni.com/users/4/0/kennen.png" alt="" />
<img src="http://images.lasuni.com/users/6/0/kennen.png" alt="" />
<img src="http://images.lasuni.com/users/3/0/kennen.png" alt="" />
<img src="http://images.lasuni.com/users/7/0/kennen.png" alt="" />
<img src="http://images.lasuni.com/users/1/0/kennen.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow img.active');
    if ($active.is(':last')) {
        $active.hide().removeClass('active');
        $('#slideshow img:first').show().addClass('active');
    }else{
        $active.hide().removeClass('active').next().show().addClass('active');
    }
}

$(function () {
    $('#slideshow img').not('.active').hide()
    setInterval(slideSwitch, 400);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hLvQV/)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid one missing picture I had to change the third line of the last answer to

```
if ($active.is(':nth-last-child(1)')) {
```